# In R, apply a function to the rows of a data frame and return a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

I am trying to apply a self-written function to the rows of a data frame.

```
library(dplyr) # only used for data_frame
DF = data_frame(x = c(50, 49, 20), y = c(132, 124, 130), z = c(0.82, 1, 0.63))

     x     y     z
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    50   132  0.82
2    49   124  1.00
3    20   130  0.63
```

The actual data frame has thousands of rows, this is just a sample.

My function is very complicated and does many things, and in the end I get for each row of DF a new row.
Let's say for simplicity that the function adds 1 to column 1, 2 to column 2 and 3 to column 3 (this of course can be vectorized, but my function, lets call it Funct, does much more).
So:

```
Funct = function(DF) {
   DF[1]= DF[1]+1
   DF[2] = DF[2]+2
   DF[3] = DF[3]+3
   return(DF)
}
```

How do I apply this function in the most efficient way to get in the end a new data frame with the output:

```
> DF
     x     y     z
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    51   134  3.82
2    50   126  4.00
3    21   132  3.63
```

Comment: Why are you not using a matrix if all dataframe is same type? I believe your question is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In simplifying your actual use case, you are leaving out important details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apply` is a bad option for data frames because it is designed for matrices, and thus will coerce a data frame input to a matrix before iterating. Aside from occasionally being an expensive conversion (which has to be reversed afterwards), the real problem with this is that matrices in R can only handle a single type, whereas data frames can have a different type for each variable. Thus, while it will work fine for the data here, you'll often end up with type coercion happening in a matrix you can't see, when numbers are coerced to character because another column is a factor. If you really want to use `apply`, explicitly coerce to a matrix beforehand so you can see what it is working with, and you'll avoid a lot of annoying bugs.

But there's a better option than `apply`: instead, iterate in parallel over the variables (columns) and then coerce the resulting list back to a data frame. `purrr::pmap_dfr` will handle both parts:

```r
library(tidyverse)

DF = data_frame(x = c(50, 49, 20), 
                y = c(132, 124, 130), 
                z = c(0.82, 1, 0.63))

DF %>% 
    pmap_dfr(~list(x = ..1 + 1,
                   y = ..2 + 2,
                   z = ..3 + 3))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1   51.  134.  3.82
#> 2   50.  126.  4.00
#> 3   21.  132.  3.63
```

You can do the same thing in base R with

```r
do.call(rbind, do.call(Map, 
                       c(function(...){
                           data.frame(x = ..1 + 1,
                                      y = ..2 + 2,
                                      z = ..3 + 3)
                       }, 
                       DF)
))
#>    x   y    z
#> 1 51 134 3.82
#> 2 50 126 4.00
#> 3 21 132 3.63
```

...though it's not terribly pretty.

Note that a vectorized solution, when possible, will be much, much faster.

```r
DF %>% 
    mutate(x = x + 1,
           y = y + 2,
           z = z + 3)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1   51.  134.  3.82
#> 2   50.  126.  4.00
#> 3   21.  132.  3.63
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `apply`...

```
DF2 <- as.data.frame(t(apply(DF, 1, Funct)))

DF2
   x   y    z
1 51 134 3.82
2 50 126 4.00
3 21 132 3.63
```

Comment: This works well given all columns are `numeric` (as in the example provided). If the user over-simplified the data and there are other types in the frame, this solution will not work (well).

Comment: Is this the most efficient way for thousands of rows? how about something like mapply - Im not sure I know exactly how to use it

Comment: @r2evans, yes the data frame is only numeric

Comment: As one R gold member user, [@DavidArenburg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001626/david-arenburg) puts it as #1 in his bio: *If you are working with data.frames, forget there is a function called apply- whatever you do - don't use it.*

Comment: @OmryAtia `mapply` works if you have a function of several variables, but you are using a function of one variable (albeit a vector), which is what each iteration of `apply` passes to `Funct`.  I'd have thought this was a pretty efficient way of doing it, although it would be fastest if you converted `DF` to a matrix rather than a dataframe.

Comment: @Parfait, I believe the most-apt frame-equivalent of `apply(DF,1,func)` could be `do.call(rbind, by(DF, seq_len(nrow(DF)), func))` ... a bit awkward, but it does what is desired with `apply` without the conversion woes (albeit with some expense).

Comment: Omry Atia, think of `mapply` as "zipping" lists together: `mapply(func, list1, list2, list3)` iterates into `func(list1[1], list2[1], list3[1])` then `func(list1[2], list2[2], list3[2])`, etc. This is not what you need here. (Caveat: one *could* make it work, but it is not really ideal given other more-efficient methods.)

Answer (score 1):

If this is perfectly `numeric`, you can get away with

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(as.matrix(DF), 1, `+`, c(1,2,3))))
as.data.frame(t(apply(DF, 1, Funct))) # better, per AndrewGustar's answer
```

which will likely be the fastest you can do. However, if you have anything other than `numeric` in the data (e.g., `integer` or *gasp* `character`), using `apply` will result in conversion out of `numeric`, not what you want. (I am including `as.matrix` in the first example to demonstrate what is actually happening within `apply`, not that you actually need that in your code. This matrix conversion is why `apply` can be problematic to non-homogenous frames.)

As was stated in other comments, if your data is truly all-`numeric`, you will gain significant performance (and, if relevant, storage) improvements by converting it to a `matrix` and dealing with it as such.

For heterogenous-class frames (or if you just want to be robust for future changes), try this:

```
do.call(rbind, by(DF, seq_len(nrow(DF)), Funct))
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#       x     y     z
# * <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    51   134  3.82
# 2    50   126  4.00
# 3    21   132  3.63
```

**Edit**

If you need to include all data when you aggregate each row:

1. Pass the whole `DF` as another argument, such as `Funct(DF1, DFall)`. This would be called as `by(DF, seq_len(nrow(DF)), Funct, DFall=DF)`;
2. If your access to all rows is merely an aggregation that can be calculated once and passed to `Funct` as an additional argument (think `Funct(DF1, DFall)`), then do that calc once, and then pass it as above in place of the whole frame;
3. Otherwise, use a `for` loop. None of the offered solutions (nor that I can think of now) facilitate this type of view.

Comment: This is a good general solution. What if my function has to work  on DF both row-wise and refer to all the rows of it (Funct, as I said, is much more complicated than what I wrote). The do.call function calls it row-wise and the rest of the rows are not in the environmet