# Storing extracted values from functions after applying down rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, apply, sample-size

I have a `data.frame` with two columns `$P1` and `$P2`, both numeric. I'd like to run the `power.prop.test` in `library(stats)`,by row, and have a third column created that prints only the `$n` value from the function results.  The test should be conducted with `power=0.80` in the arguments. The data looks as follows:

```
structure(list(P1 = c(0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02), P2 = c(0.022, 
0.024, 0.026, 0.028, 0.03, 0.032)), .Names = c("P1", "P2"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

There would be a third column, say, `$N`, where the first element would be 80681.38, the second would be 21108.38, and so forth.

Also, should note that same number repeats in `$P1` because I `head()` the original `data.frame` that had `rep(seq())` of several numbers.

Can some assist?
Cheers!

Comment: I've tried `apply(tdata, 1, power.prop.test(p1=data$P1, p2=data$P2, power=0.80)$n` and                                                                        
`N<-function (p1, p2, power) {
  outcome<-power.prop.test(p1, p2, power)
  return(outcome)
}`

Comment: `apply` is a bad idea ([see here for why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49697248/4497050)); `purrr::pmap` or the like is a better option. `broom::tidy` is very helpful to turn the test results into a nice data frame. All together: `purrr::pmap_dfr(df, ~broom::tidy(power.prop.test(p1 = .x, p2 = .y, power = 0.8)))`, or to just add an `n` column, `df$n <- pmap_dbl(df, ~power.prop.test(p1 = .x, p2 = .y, power = 0.8)$n)`

Comment: or in all base R, `df$n <- mapply(function(P1, P2){power.prop.test(p1 = P1, p2 = P2, power = 0.8)$n}, df$P1, df$P2)`

Comment: That last one worked perfectly! Apologies, I'm still a novice at this: when I run the third line, I get an error that it could not find function `pmap_dbl()`. What package is that in? I installed `purrr`, `broom`, and `tidyverse`.

Comment: `pmap` (and variants) is from purrr, which you can load explicitly or via `library(tidyverse)`. broom is installed by tidyverse, but not loaded by it.